# sortable ul in sortable ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i tried to run a sortable ul in an other sortable ul.

here is my code.

```
<ul id="list1">
<li>bla bla
    <ul id="list2">
      <li>bla bla</li>
      <li>bla bla</li>
      <li>bla bla</li>
   </ul>
<li>bla bla</li>
</ul>



$("#list1").sortable({});
$("#list2").sortable({});
```

here list1s sortable success but list2 not! i searched everywhere but there is nothing!

P.S: i can't use multisoratble or nestable 'cos of my project and i'm using jquery 1.10.2

i noticed that the problem is i create list2 ul dynamicly via jquery so that it can't sorted.

Comment: both of list are sortable, I was checked it

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6f3M/ it works

Comment: yes Farnabaz  i've forgot close 'li' tag. but i'm using jquery 1.10.2 version. so that it is not work @karthikr